# Python: Can't turn string into JSON

Tags: python, json, decode

For the past few hours, I've been fighting to get a string into a JSON dict.  I've tried everything from json.loads(... which throws an error:

```
requestInformation = json.loads(entry["request"]["postData"]["text"])
//throws this error
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes:
```

to stripping out the slashes using a medley of re.sub('\\','',mystring) ,mystring.sub(... to no effect.  My problem string looks like so

```
'{items:[{n:\\'PackageChannel.GetUnitsInConfigurationForUnitType\\',ps:[{n:\\'unitType\\',v:"ActionTemplate"}]}]}'
```

The origin of this string is that it's a HAR dump from Google Chrome.  I think those backslashes are from it being escaped somewhere along the way because the bulk of the HAR file doesn't contain them, but they do appear commonly in any field labeled "text".

```
"postData": {
        "mimeType": "application/json",
        "text": "{items:[{n:'PackageChannel.GetUnitsInConfigurationForUnitType',ps:[{n:'unitType',v:\"Analysis\"}]}]}"
}
```

**EDIT**  I eventually gave up on turning the text above into JSON and instead opted for regex.  Sometimes the slashes showed up, sometimes they didn't based on what I was viewing the text in and that made it difficult to work with.

Comment: thats valid javascript object, but invalid json and invalid python dict. http://json.org, may be find loose json parser.

Comment: the error is not about backslashes btw, it is complaining keys are not double quoted

Comment: with regex 're' module, `>>> json.loads(re.sub('(\w+):', r'"\1":', a.replace("'", '"')))
{u'items': [{u'ps': [{u'v': u'Analysis', u'n': u'unitType'}], u'n': u'PackageChannel.GetUnitsInConfigurationForUnitType'}]}
`

Answer (score 0):

the `json` module wants a string where the keys are also wrapped in double quotes

so the string below would work:

```
mystring = '{"items":[{"n":"PackageChannel.GetUnitsInConfigurationForUnitType", "ps":[{"n":"unitType","v":"ActionTemplate"}]}]}'
myjson = json.loads(mystring)
```

This function should remove the double backslashes and put double quotes around your keys.

```
import json, re

def make_jsonable(mystring):
    # we'll use this regex to find any key that doesn't contain any of: {}[]'",
    key_regex = "([\,\[\{](\s+)?[^\"\{\}\,\[\]]+(\s+)?:)" 

    mystring = re.sub("[\\\]", "", mystring) # remove any backslashes
    mystring = re.sub("\'", "\"", mystring)  # replace single quotes with doubles
    match = re.search(key_regex, mystring) 

    while match:
        start_index = match.start(0)
        end_index = match.end(0)
        print(mystring[start_index+1:end_index-1].strip())
        mystring = '%s"%s"%s'%(mystring[:start_index+1], mystring[start_index+1:end_index-1].strip(), mystring[end_index-1:])

        match = re.search(key_regex, mystring)
    return mystring
```

I couldn't directly test it on the first string you wrote, the double/single quotes don't match up, but on the one in the last code sample it works.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need a r before JSON String, or replace all \ with \\

This works:

```
   import json
    validasst_json = r'''{
        "postData": {
            "mimeType": "application/json",
            "text": "{items:[{n:'PackageChannel.GetUnitsInConfigurationForUnitType',ps:[{n:'unitType',v:\"Analysis\"}]}]}"
        }
    }'''

    txt = json.loads(validasst_json)
    print(txt["postData"]['mimeType'])
    print(txt["postData"]['text'])
```

Comment: he is decoding ﾞtextﾞ field of that object

Comment: I'm just showing how to get a string into a JSON dict, where he is facing issues doing that.

Comment: then it is not the answer

Comment: downvote not fair, Question title says Can't convert string to JSON, that's what I trying to do..what other glitch we see here apart from that?

Comment: you are decoding different json object, that OP already have it as python object - entry["request"]["postData"]["text"] - no error - read the code more.

Comment: got it, but can someone update the title and content of this question, looks like he is asking to convert string into python object i.e JSON Dict.